# Update a boolean in items to approve them on website - Multiple items

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I have created a list of items from a database. These are shown correctly. Now i would like to save the changed booleans to my database. How can I receive all these items to my controller so i can loop through them by foreach or something?

### CONTROLLER

```
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    private SocialGEOContext db = new SocialGEOContext();
    public ActionResult ApproveItems()
    {
        Utility ut = new Utility();
        IEnumerable<Item> items;
        items = ut.GetAllDistrictItems();
        return View(items);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ApproveItems( ??? )
    {
        ???
    }
```

In the HttpPost i tried

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ApproveItems( IEnumerable<Item> ViewItems )
    {
        foreach (Item item in ViewItems)
        {
            var testje = item.ItemTitle;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

But the ViewItems is empty

### PAGE

```
@model IEnumerable<LibModels.Item> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ItemsByDistrict";
}

<h2>All items from district</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemTitle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemCreateddate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemDescription)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ItemApproved)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a for loop in order for the model binding to work

```
@for(int i; i < Model.Count; i++) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ItemID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ItemTitle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ItemCreateddate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ItemDescription)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ItemApproved)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

See [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for a good breakdown on model binding collections

Note: you'll need to call `ToList()` on the model so that you can use indexing

In other words in your action method:

```
public ActionResult ApproveItems()
    {
        Utility ut = new Utility();
        IEnumerable<Item> items;
        items = ut.GetAllDistrictItems();
        return View(items.ToList());
    }
```

And then change the model in the view:

```
@model IList<LibModels.Item>
```

Comment: Indexing on a IEnumerable is not allowed... so i changed the code to:
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ElementAt(i).ItemID)
                </td>

But this still gives me an empty ViewItems

Comment: That won't work because now you've cahnged the name property of the input elements (check out the rendered html) and broken mvc's ability to bind the model.

Comment: Cast the ienumerable to a list and change the model in the view to a list so you can index in the loop and it will work.

Comment: Ok nice, this worked, thanks a lot. One more question i need the itemID aswell, but in the returned list the id is still NULL, i know i can fix this with :
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ItemID). But is there another solution for this? Because the user may not edit the itemID.

Comment: Yes, in addition to `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ItemID)`, add `@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ItemID)`

Answer (score 0):

Your page contains an editor only for `item.ItemApproved` but in the post method you are trying to get `item.ItemTitle`.  Try changing the controller post method to:

```
foreach (Item item in ViewItems) {
   var testje = item.ItemApproved;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make a diffirence because ViewItems is null

Comment: I'm assuming that `Item` is the same as `LibModels.Item`.  Have you tried changing the post method argument to `IEnumerable<LibModels.Item>`?

Comment: Yes the Item and LibModels.Item are the same. So IEnumberable<LibModels.Item> would give me the same result, it is still empty. Thx for responding btw

Comment: _Would_ give the same result or _does_ give the same result?  MVC can be picky about how you specify a type.

Comment: It does give the same result :)